# Get thumbnail URL from image URL

Tags: android

I have a String URL pointing to an image stored on the external storage of my device:

```
String imageUrl = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0823.jpg"
```

I want to get query the `MediaStore` to get the thumbnail for this image. This is what I do right now:

```
private String getImageThumbnailPath(Context ctx, String imageUrl){

    Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnails(
            ctx.getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(new File(imageUrl)),
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
            null);

    String url = "";
    if( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        url = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA ) );
        cursor.close();
    }
    return url;
}
```

However, calling this method and printing it's content shows nothing (the cursor is empty).

How do I query the `MediaStore` for the thumbnail url associated with my image URL?

**Edit**

I've also tried to parse the Uri directly from the image URL, as so:

```
Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnails(
        ctx.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(imageUrl),
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
        null);
```

But the result is the same.

Comment: Check Uri value `Uri.fromFile(new File(imageUrl))`

Comment: it is `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0823.jpg` @dieter_h

Comment: Should be file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0823.jpg

Comment: Sorry, ignore that last comment. The output from `System.out.println(Uri.fromFile(new File(imageUrl)));` is `file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0823.jpg`

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: I'm also wondering if you found the solution. i cannot seem to retrieve thumbnail using getThumbnail. It returns null even though image id is valid

Answer (score 7):

Following code works if you have pick image from gallery, otherwise we can not have thumbnail, and we have to create thumbnail.

First you have to find the **MediaStore.Images.Media._ID**

```
public String[] getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
            proj, null, null, null);
    int path_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(proj[0]);
    int id_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(proj[1]);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return new String[] { cursor.getString(path_index),
            cursor.getLong(id_index) + "" };
}
```

From above `getRealPathFromURI` now we have `MediaStore.Images.Media._ID`, use this id to find thumbnail.

```
public static Bitmap getThumbnail(ContentResolver contentResolver, long id) {
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}, // Which columns
                // to return
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?", // Which rows to return
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, // Selection arguments
                null);// order

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String filePath = cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();
            int rotation = 0;
            try {
                ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(filePath);
                int exifRotation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
                if (exifRotation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {
                    switch (exifRotation) {
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                            rotation = 180;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                            rotation = 270;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                            rotation = 90;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("getThumbnail", e.toString());
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    contentResolver, id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
            if (rotation != 0) {
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.setRotate(rotation);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                        bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            }
            return bitmap;
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

To use above **LOC**

**Updated**

```
String[] imageInfo = getRealPathFromURI(Uri.parse("YOUR_IMAGE_PATH"));
yourImageView.setImageBitmap(getThumbnail(getActivity()
                    .getContentResolver(), Long.parseLong(imageInfo[1])));
```

`Uri.parse("YOUR_IMAGE_PATH")` is contentUri

Comment: What's contentUri in the first method?

Comment: In `getRealPathFromURI` method, `getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
            proj, null, null, null);` returns `null`. My contentUri is `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0827.jpg`. Any idea?

Comment: I know it's been  4 years sine you posted this response but I'm having problem with MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail method. It returns null for some reason. I stepped thorough my code and I can see query returns proper cursor, and I could extract image_id from it.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure the [ThumbnailUtils](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html) class can help you on this.

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
```

It returns a Bitmap and yous should **check if it not null before using it**. Sometimes, corrupted files return null thumbnails.

If you are not supporting anything below API level 8, you **should** be using this.

**UPDATE**

If you need the thumbnail path, please use this method,

```
public String getThumbnailPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    String result = null;
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    long imageId = cursor.getLong(column_index);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(
            getContentResolver(), imageId,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
            null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I might have been vague in my question, but I want the **url** of the bitmap, which is stored in the MediaStore database

Comment: Its working perfectly for you. I think you should try with it first. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried it, managedQuery is deprecated. I used contentResolver.query() instead, but it returned null.

Comment: Thre's a reason for it being deprecated tho, is it not?

Comment: That's not the scope of this answer. If you can try it and confirm its not working, I can try to help you in other way. But I won't be able to help, if you are not ready to cooperate. Thanks.

Comment: @Vishwa Where did I ever mention ThumbnailUtils being deprecated? I said managedQuery is deprecated.

Comment: @Marcus Did you try the solution? It is working perfectly for me. I took the time just to help you, and it would have been really good if you could just try it.

Comment: @AritraRoy Cursor cursor =  contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null); cursor is null

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to resize and save thumbnail behind original image :

```
private void resizer(String local_path, int original_image_w, int original_image_h){
    if(local_path.length() > 0){
        int imgW = (int) (original_image_w * 0.10); // Can Change By Device Width
        int imgH = (int) (original_image_h * 0.10); // Can Change By Device height
        Log.d("TAG_RESIZE", "Resizer, W : "+imgW+" , H : "+imgH);
        Log.d("TAG_RESIZE", "Resizer local path : "+(new File(local_path).exists() ? "Exist" : "Not Exist")+" , \n"+local_path);
        String ex = local_path.substring(local_path.lastIndexOf('.')+1, local_path.length());
        // ExceptionHelpers.eLog(G.Logs.Error, "Slider Downloader Image ex : " + ex);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap dlBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(local_path, options);
        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(dlBitmap, imgW, imgH, true);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(local_path.replace("."+ex, "_thumb."+ex));
            if(ex.toLowerCase().startsWith("jpg") || ex.toLowerCase().startsWith("jpeg")){
                resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, fos);
            }else if(ex.toLowerCase().startsWith("png")){
                resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fos);
            }

            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ExceptionHelpers.catchMessage(e); // My Custom Class To Log Errors, Useful To Save Error Logs And Send To Server
        }
    }
}
```

Also it will capture Memory Storage, But Faster than RunTime resize

Comment: This is what `Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);` does, why reinvent the wheel? Also, it's not what I asked for.

Comment: @Marcus told you reasone of use it

Answer (score -2):

You have pick an image from gallery, otherwise we can not have thumbnail. You can first launch a intent to pick an image from gallery like this.

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
```

after this in your onActivityResult do this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
            Bitmap thumbnail = new File(intent.getExtras().get("data"));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```