# How to get thumbnail from Audio URL in android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to get thumbnail from Audio URL? I have list of Audio files URL and I want to show the thumbnail of each audio.

Comment: You can get a reference from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029011/get-thumbnail-url-from-image-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource("YOUR URL", new HashMap<String, String>());
    try {
        final byte[] coverImage = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(coverImage, 0, coverImage.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

use the bitmap and show it in image view

Comment: I am getting error "MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI: getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed". There is no Album art embedded in my Audio file. Is it essential to add Album art with each URL for this ?

Comment: If its there you will get bitmap else it will enter catch block , you can have a place holder image there